# Run bash command through Appium

Tags: bash, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I've got a bash script that cleans up my temp files between testing, so that each new test can start with a clean slate.

I need to invoke this script at the end of every test. Is it possible to run bash commands or execute a bash script with Appium?

Right now the tests are written in C# - ideally I would pass the contents of the bash script using C# through to Appium.

I've looked at `executeScript()` but if I understand correctly this executes JavaScript only. How can I achieve executing bash?

Answer (score 1):

**Write a bash script file, then execute the file in your code**

*A bash script named* ***cleanslate.command***

```
#!/bin/bash
Your clean slate command here…
```

*At the end of your code, something like…*

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\path\to\cleanslate.command");
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My C# is running on windows, but Appium is running on the Mac. (I'm using an iOSDriver to connect to the Mac from Windows, and run the tests on an iOS Simulator). Therefore the bash script would need to run on the mac, but invoked from Windows. Can the above code be used to do this?

Comment: @user1775598 If you have a way of accessing the file system on your mac, from your windows machine, then this way is great.  Although I would recommend centralising to one machine (i.e. running scripts and having the appium running on your mac).

Comment: I suggest having Appium test scripts run on your Mac as well. Less complicated